# Going from IQueryable<IEnumerable<myObj>> to IEnumerable<myObj>

Tags: c#, beginner, .net, linq, collections

I have a "GetPersonsPerDepartment()" method returning a `IQueryable<IEnumerable<Person>>` while I'm trying to get a simple `List<Person>` or `IEnumerable<Person>` with all the persons from every department. I wrote a simple method GetAllPersons() that solves this with a loop but I feel I must be missing a simple command to get the same result:

```
private List<Person> GetAllPersons()
{
    List<Person> allPersons = new List<Person>();

    foreach(var Persons in GetPersonsPerDepartment())
    {
        allPersons.AddRange(Persons);
    }

    return allPersons;
}

private IQueryable<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPersonsPerDepartment()
{
    IQueryable<IEnumerable<Person>> Persons;

    using (var context = MySource.GetPersonsContext())
    {
        var library = "Personlist";
        var PersonFolderList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(library);
        context.Load<List>(PersonFolderList);

        var PersonFolderListItems = PersonFolderList.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
        context.Load<ListItemCollection>(PersonFolderListItems);

        context.ExecuteQuery();

        Persons = PersonFolderListItems.Where(x => x.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.Folder).Select(x => GetPersonsFromFolderListItem(x, context, PersonFolderList));
    }

    return Persons;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___). As in, `allPersons.SelectMany(s => s);`. This flattens the sequence for you.

Comment: Not only one-liner code but also a one-liner review - there should be a badge for it ;-]

Comment: There seems to be :). The +10 answer badge.

Comment: While correct, I find `SelectMany(s => s)` does not really convey the "concatenate all of these together" meaning very well. If you're not a heavy LINQ user, it's going to confuse you initially. (I've had coworkers be confused by it.) One might consider wrapping this inside a method: `public static ConcatAll<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> e) { return e.SelectMany(i = i); }`.

Comment: @jpmc26 _I've had coworkers be confused by it_ - then they either should learn how to use LINQ correctly or leave writing software to people who can understand something as simple as  `SelectMany`.. Creating extensions like `ConcatAll` is even more confusing.

Comment: @t3chb0t Giving things appropriate, straightforward names that clearly communicates their behavior increases confusion? *Wat.* The best kind of code is code that can be understood at a glance. There is absolutely nothing wrong with being clear enough that other people understand something immediately. Honestly, we'd all be better off if the .NET standard library was written with that mindset. How did you get 34k rep on a code review site thinking like that?

Answer (score 3):

#### Is this a bug or dirty workaround?

There is one thing in your code that sooner or later will bite you and I don't quite understnd why it didn't...

You're returing an `IQueryable<IEnumerable<Person>>` after you have disposed your `context`. I'm not sure what workarounds your are using there because you provided very little context but your code actually shouldn't work.

I suppose it's Entity Framework and with it you should never return `IQuerybale` if you're disposing its context by the same method but always materialize the query before returnig the result, e.g. with `ToList` etc.

Comment: Returning an `IQueryable` is a perfectly valid strategy with EF--it won't actually do the query until you materialize it, and it allows other parts of the code to add additional filters/tranformations to the data that will be executed on the DB, making it more performant. Of course, this only works in certain cases where you get the context when you need it, instead of being in a `using` block (like if you are working from an `IGenericRepository` type thing).

Comment: @Hosch250 I know how it works and clarified what I meant ;-] OP does have a `using` block here thus it's super confusing why it actually works... it shouldn't and IMO there is some _dirty_ workaround becuase if it's materialized then it shouldn't be an `IQueryable` and if it's not then the context should not be disposed.